# Count the element only if it has a number before comma

Tags: python, regex, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to count the element only if it has a number(at the end) before comma.

Examples:

> 12,12,12 = 3
>    BOOK,,NO,06,07 = 5  <- This is supposed to be 2
>   401-402-403-404-405, 301-302-303-304-305 = 2 <- This should be 10
>   G2,G3,G4 <- It should be 3

The data has all sort of special characters and stuff that I've replaced with comma except "-"  and seems to create problem too. Some books have been assigned a-2, b-01 so this should be counted as 1 and not 2. what do i do?

Code:

```
import string
data['book_no']=data.book_no.replace(r'[!"#$%&\'()*+/.:;<>?@[\]^_`{|}~]', ',', regex=True)
data['book_no']=data.book_no.str.strip(string.punctuation);
data['total_books']=data.book_no.str.split(r'[!"#$%&\'()*+,/:;<>?@[\]^_`{|}~]').str.len()
```

Comment: I don't understand why the last one should be 10, and not 2, according to your rules.

Comment: `data['total_books']=data['book_no'].str.findall(r'\d+(?=,)|(?<=,)\d+').str.len()`?

Comment: @alkasm Because there are 10 books  not 2. Just wrong separator has been used

Comment: Does `.findall(r'\d+(?=,)|(?<=,)\d+').str.len()` work for you, or do you want to also account for `-` separated numbers?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Awesome. It is almost efficient but for this "G2,G3,G4" It  gave the output as 2 but it should be 3

Comment: But `G4` is not a number, after the comma, there is no number here.

Comment: I think last element starting with letter is being ignored

Comment: Starting with a number is not compulsory. Ending with a number is

Comment: So, `.str.findall(r'\d+(?![^,])|(?<=,)\d+').str.len()` works?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew My code already does kinda similar thing. With your solution we are almost close to get the correct solution

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes. Done. Amazing

Comment: Please add it as the answer. I'll accept it. Also please add the explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
data['total_books']=data['book_no'].str.findall(r'\d+(?![^,])|(?<=,)\d+').str.len()
```

The regex matches

- `\d+(?![^,])` - 1+ digits (`\d+`) that are followed with either a comma or end of string (`(?![^,])` = `(?=,|$)`)
- `|` - or
- `(?<=,)\d+` - 1+ digits (`\d+`) preceded with a comma (`(?<=,)`).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4CmEsX/1) and the regex graph:

[image]

Comment: Worked. Amazing knowledgeable stuff!

Answer (score 0):

I would try to split at each dash or comma, and then check for each element whether it is numeric or not. One way of doing that would be:

```
def custom_count(your_string):
    split_str = your_string.replace('-', ',').split(',')
    return sum([x.strip().isdigit() for x in split_str])
```

This works well on your examples:

```
In [2]: custom_count('BOOK,,NO,06,07')
Out [2]: 2

In [3]: custom_count('401-402-403-404-405, 301-302-303-304-305')
Out [3]: 10
```

---

**Warning1**: `is.digit()` does not work on numbers with a decimal point:

```
'3.14159'.isdigit()
False
```

**Warning2**: Also, note that thousands separators will be split into different numeric values, and will be counted multiple times. One million, for example:

```
custom_count('1,000,000')
3
```

Comment: I believe OP just wants the last character to be a digit, not the string itself.